# toOptionHash returns an array of null

Tags: magento-1.8, collection

## Synopsis

I am attempting to create a drop-down box with JavaScript where by I would like to dump my collection results through `toOptionHash`, however all i am getting is an array of null values.

I will be encoding to JSON and setting the response body however this is outside the scope of this question.

```
$result = Mage::getModel('cutting/plate_thickness')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.spec_id', $specId);

Zend_Debug::dump( $result->toOptionHash('id', 'size') );
```

This outputs:

```
array(41) {
  [1] => NULL
  [2] => NULL
    ... snip ...
  [40] => NULL
  [41] => NULL
}
```

Although I *could* do the following - I want to make use of the `toOptionHash` which is what it exists for?

```
$result = Mage::getModel('cutting/plate_thickness')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.spec_id', $specId);

$data = [];
foreach ($result as $record) {
    $data[$record->getData('id')] = $record->getData('size');
}
```

Comment: does `Zend_Debug::dump($result->getData());` show the proper data, if so double check indexes, like `id` being `entity_id`, etc.

Comment: The odd thing is those keys in my array are accurate to those of the `id` column in the table (also, they don't start from 0, which indicates this is no coincidence) yet the values (of the `size` field) are all `NULL`.

Comment: disable community and local code pools and test, possibly something overriding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## El Conclusion

After further debugging something stood out like a sore thumb which originally I overlooked, that was the broken core functionality as per-usual:

Eventually `Varien_Db_Data_Collection` is inherited so when I execute `toOptionArray` or `toOptionHash` **NO arguments are parsed thus why NULL is apparent**

### Solution 1

Is to ensure that you only use `id` as your id field and `name` as your value field.

### Solution 2

To extend `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` implementing the `toOptionHash` and `toOptionArray` methods to override those defined within `Varien_Db_Data_Collection`:

```
public function toOptionArray($idField = 'id', $valueField = 'name', $additional = [])
{
    return $this->_toOptionArray($idField, $valueField, $additional);
}

public function toOptionHash($idField = 'id', $valueField = 'name', $additional = [])
{
    return $this->_toOptionHash($idField, $valueField, $additional);
}
```

---

This is the snippet from lib/Varien/Db/Data/Collection.php to highlight the issue discovered.

```
protected function _toOptionArray($valueField='id', $labelField='name', $additional=array())
{
    $res = array();
    $additional['value'] = $valueField;
    $additional['label'] = $labelField;

    foreach ($this as $item) {
        foreach ($additional as $code => $field) {
            $data[$code] = $item->getData($field);
        }
        $res[] = $data;
    }
    return $res;
}

public function toOptionArray()
{
    return $this->_toOptionArray();
}

public function toOptionHash()
{
    return $this->_toOptionHash();
}

protected function _toOptionHash($valueField='id', $labelField='name')
{
    $res = array();
    foreach ($this as $item) {
        $res[$item->getData($valueField)] = $item->getData($labelField);
    }
    return $res;
}
```